# Why does Nexenta seem to ignore my /etc/system settings?

Tags: nfs, tcp, nexenta

I am trying to tune my NFS performance, but for some reason nexenta is ignoring whatever I specify in /etc/system. In the following screen shot it becomes apparent that my manual settings are not being picked up, why? I realize the web gui does give me the option of specifying the tcp_recv_hiwat and tcp_xmit_hiwat, but what about the other variables?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tcp_cwnd_max is obsolete on Solaris 11 which uses instead:

```
ipadm set-prop -p _cwnd_max=8388608 tcp
```

Nexenta latest release might support ipadm too.

Answer (score 0):

Changes to `/etc/system` require a reboot in Nexenta.